# HttpWebRequest Not able to call API from insider the container Dotnet

Tags: docker, api, .net-core, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient

```
            HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestendpoint);
            // Set the Headers
            WebReq.Method = methodType.ToUpper();
            WebReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorisation);
            WebReq.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            WebReq.Date = dateValue; // use datetime value GMT time
            if (content != null)
            {
                //setting content
                WebReq.Headers.Add("Content-Type", CONTENT_TYPE_PREFIX);
                WebReq.Headers.Add("Content-Length", content.Length.ToString());
                Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                WebReq.ContentType = CONTENT_TYPE_PREFIX;
                WebReq.ContentLength = content.Length;

                Stream newStream = WebReq.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
                newStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content), 0, content.Length); // Send the data.
                newStream.Close();
            }

            // Get the Response - Status OK
            HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
            // Status information about the request
```

I am not able to call an API from inside the docker container but this code is working fine on my local windows visual studio. I have checked every thing insider docker because other APIs working, docker have internet access and ports are also exposed.

I found the one github thread but its for .net 1.1 I am using .net 3.1, but still struggling  to find out the solution.